# Checking AVX processor's support in an app. linked against it

Tags: visual-c++

I am developing the application, that uses AVX instructions for 3D rendering.
Should the simplified code below work fine?

```
INT WINAPI wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE,
    _In_ LPWSTR,
    _In_ int)
{
    if (!Mnd_CheckAVXAvailability())
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, g_ErrStrNoAVX, g_ErrStrExceptionTitle, MB_ICONERROR | MB_TASKMODAL | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_TOPMOST);
        return 1;
    }   
    return Run(hInstance);
}
```

P. S.
The problem would be in global variables, but I hope the code is OK there.

I highly appreciate the help.

Comment: Use __cpuid or [GetEnabledXStateFeatures()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenabledxstatefeatures)

Comment: Thank you very much, a question is a bit different. The Mnd_CheckAVXAvailability() works, I have found sample code through the Internet. My scenario is: I start my .exe on a processor that does not have AVX. Will be shown that message box or application will crash? The idea is similiar to delayed loaded DLLs. I want to warn user on a legacy system, not loosing AVX in the binary file.

Comment: How that function works requires mnd reading.  You have no guarantee that there isn't any initialization code in the program that runs *before* WinMain() is entered.  Like C++ constructors of global objects.  Just never write code that you cannot easily test, always explicitly state minimum installation requirements.

Comment: I understand, that it could work, but this scenario is not guaranted. Is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir @hans-passant is right. I have delayed the initialization of DirectXMath globals and the test works :)
I have executed the program with AVX512, which my CPU does not support. It is possible to write such technology aware code in one module.